# How are variables declared in constructor functions in JavaScript treated?

Tags: javascript

```
function jQueryValidatorWrapper(formId, rules, messages) {
    var validator = $("form:visible[id='" + formId + "']").validate({
                         onchange: false,
                         messages: messages,
                         rules: rules
                     });

    this.validate = function (hideErrors) {
        var showErrorMessage = hideErrors ? false : true;

        // What does 'validator' refer to?
        var result = validator.form();
    };
}
```

When I execute this,

```
var validatorObj = new jQueryValidatorWrapper('testForm', [], []);
validatorObj.validate();
```

The `jQueryValidatorWrapper` function had only one method declared with `this`, so when the constructor executed, it simply created an object with the `validate` method.

What happens to `validator` variable declared inside `jQueryValidatorWrapper`? It is not prefixed with `this` so it is not part of the object being constructed.

Is the `validator` variable a global? or is it part of the closure which is the `validate` method?

Comment: `validator` is not a global variable... it will exists in the closure though

Comment: A constructor function is still a function. There is no difference between how local variables are handled or scope works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local `validator` variable is not global; it's merely accessible in the `validate` method because of the closure.

It can be considered a "private member" of the `jQueryValidatorWrapper` object, per Douglas Crockford's article here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Same goes for the 3 constructor parameters.

Comment: So, if I were to create multiple instances of jQueryValidatorWrapper with different data for the 3 constructor parameters each time, would the closure environment be modified for the previous instances?

Comment: Nope, they each get their own copy. Here's a fiddle to illustrate that: http://jsfiddle.net/sck02myt/

Comment: @Lakeland-FL—each time a function is called, an entirely new execution context is created so an entirely new closure is also created in this instance.